# To find records which are part of comma-separated list of Id's SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

It have 2 tables like this:

`t_recipe`:

```
RecipeId        Name              InsertDate 
----------------------------------------------
1             Mutton            9/6/2015 0:00
2             Veg Biryani       9/5/2015 0:00
```

`t_recipe_ingredient`:

```
RecipeId      IngrId          InsertDate
----------------------------------------------
1             200               9/6/2015 0:00
1             201               9/5/2015 0:00
1             101               9/4/2015 0:00
1             103               9/3/2015 0:00
2             100               9/2/2015 0:00
2             500               9/6/2015 0:00
2             501               9/5/2015 0:00
2             401               9/4/2015 0:00
```

I have a stored procedure which accepts a comma-separated list of `IngrId`'s in a parameter called `MyIngredientId` like this:

```
200,201,101,103,100,500,501
```

I have to get all those recipes which can be created from the `IngrId`'s parameter. Like for above example `RecipeId = 1` can be created as all of its ingredients are part of `MyIngredientId` parameter but `RecipeId = 2` not as `IngrId = 401` is not in the list.

I need output like:

```
RecipeId         RecipeName
-----------------------------
1                Mutton
```

Comment: **STOP** using those messy comma-separated lists! They're a nightmare and cause nothing but grief. If you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer - use a **table-valued parameter** type to handle these kinds of situations much more nicely, efficiently, and without all the trouble and grief. [See the relevant MSDN documentation on using TVP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for looking and answering it @ marc , Its not an issue to remove these comma-separated lists, I can remove them and can use table value parameter.Can you please send me solution if I use table value parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc_s is right that you should use [Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can, however if you want to continue with the IN statement you could do something like this using [Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
  ;WITH CTE
  as
    (
      SELECT r.RecipeID,COUNT(*) as NumIngredientsRequired
      FROM t_recipe r
        INNER JOIN t_recipe_ingredient i on   
              r.RecipeID = i.RecipeID
        GROUP BY r.RecipeID
        -- Output:
        -- RecipeID (1) NumIngredientsRequired (4)
        -- RecipeID (2) NumIngredientsRequired (4)
    ), x as
    ( 
      SELECT r.RecipeID,r.Name, COUNT(*) as Ingredients, cte.NumIngredientsRequired
      FROM t_recipe r
      INNER JOIN cte c 
            on r.RecipeID = c.RecipeID
      INNER JOIN t_recipe_ingredient i   
            on r.RecipeID = i.Recipe
      WHERE i.IngrID IN (200,201,101,103,100,500,501)
      GROUP BY r.RecipeID,r.Name, cte.NumIngredientsRequired
      -- Output: 
      -- RecipeID (1) Name (Mutton) Ingredients (4) NumIngredientsRequired (4)
      -- RecipeID (2) Name (Veg Biryani) Ingredients (2) NumIngredientsRequired (4)
  )
    SELECT x.RecipeID,x.Name
    FROM x 
    WHERE x.NumIngredientsRequired = x.Ingredients
    -- Output:
    -- RecipeID (1) Name (Mutton)
```

Comment: Thanks Fez, if I use table value parameter then above solution can be optimized or not as it is taking a good time :-)

Comment: @ChupChapCharli yes this could be optimized using a Table-value parameter. There is a good example of how you can do this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx#Anchor_3). Did the above solution work for you?

Comment: Although I resolved it my own but your solution also worked fine :-)